# WebRTC with VPN

Tags: webrtc, vpn, peerjs

will I need STUN/TRUN-Servers, if the devices running my WebRTC-application are in a corporate VPN, or can I expect it to just work like in LAN?

I am using the [PeerJS library](http://peerjs.com/) and the [PeerServerCloud](http://peerjs.com/peerserver) for Signaling.

Answer (score 1):

if both( or all) peers are behind the corporate VPN network, then probably not. In most other cases, you would most definitely need a [TURN Server](https://github.com/coturn/coturn),
also, if your network blocks/ restricts the 443 port to internet, you would need to connect with the TURN server through TCP transport instead of the usual UDP.